# Changing URL in a CodedUI Test

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have created a codedui test in Visual Studio 2012. The problem is that I need to be able to change the URL occasionally that opens in the browser as each step of the project is updated to a new version. Apart from the fact there seems to be a number of instances where the URL appears, when I do change it, it seems to reset itself after doing a rebuild.

Is there an easier way to ensure that the URL I set does not change? I'm fairly new to the testing suite so I may have missed something glaringly obvious.

I have looked for some decent tutorials regarding the VS2012 Testing but if anybody could recommend one that I may have missed that would also be very helpful.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Coded UI Test Editor in Visual Studio Feature Pack 2 to visually update the parameter without any coding.

See the following blog post for a tutorial and info on obtaining the extension: http://windotnet.blogspot.com/#!/2011/07/coded-ui-test-editor-is-visual-studio.html

-Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can try Data Driven Coded UI.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx
You can pass various url as parameters to Coded UI.