# CodedUI Test Change URL

Tags: c#, testing, url-rewriting, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I want to run my recorded coded-ui tests in a different copy (different url- same system) my system. I need to change URL string, and i want to do it in my test file (in this case named: d01.cs)
Here it is:
I have a test name D01.cs, and here's the part i define my parameters:

```
 public void D01()
        {

            this.UIMap.D01Params.UIRtbTxt1EditText = TestContext.DataRow["test1"].ToString();
            this.UIMap.D01();

In UIMap.Designer i found this:


public class D01Params
 #region Fields
        /// <summary>
        /// Go to web page 'http://localhost:8095/Login.aspx' using new browser instance
        /// </summary>
        public string UIBlankPageWindowsInteWindowUrl = "http://localhost:8095/Login.aspx"
```

I want to write url as a parameter in my D01.cs file., i want to take it from excel if it's possible.. but i cannot find the correct property to set it. this.UIMAP... does not answer

what should i do? i tried to use:
this.UIBlankPageWindowsInteWindowUrl
but still not working.

Comment: Have you tried the answers from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376084/changing-url-in-a-codedui-test?rq=1  ?

Comment: yes i looked but i couldn't find the answer i'm looking for. The topic suggests to use test editor but i like to take my URL from the excel where i keep my other parameters as well. 
I mean, run this test, in this URL, with these parameters..

I'm fine with every field but i cant find the correct property to set my URL

Comment: BTW, i'm using the same browser. in my case, same internet explorer. ı just need to re-write URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I have gained with my experience in CUITs, The CUI Test Builder creates a params class for the methods we generate.
If you go to the definition of your method(F12), you'll find this line.

```
BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri(this.D01Params.Url));
```

you can assign your own URL to D01Params with

```
this.UIMap.D01Params.UIBlankPageWindowsInteWindowUrl = this.TestContext.DataRow["YourNewUrl"].ToString();
this.UIMap.D01Params.UIRtbTxt1EditText = TestContext.DataRow["test1"].ToString();
this.UIMap.D01();
```

Answer (score 1):

you said you wanted to import from excel but i don't see the datasource in your code. did you set DataSource for excel?

eg:

```
DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=|DataDirectory|\\Data.xls;defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true", "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

after setting the datasource, you can now access the row of data from the data source.

the syntax to access the colums is as follows:

```
string paramVal = TestContext.DataRow["Input1"]
```

Comment: it's not about excel, that's why i didnt post my connection string but here it is, if it helps: 
        [TestMethod]
        [DeploymentItem(@"C:\Test\DataFiles\Excel.xlsx")]

and in my app.config:

<add name="XXConn"
       connectionString="Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=C:\Test\DataFiles\Excel.xlsx;defaultdir=.;driverid=79‌​0;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />

Answer (score 0):

If you follow [the directions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx) in the second answer in the [link I sent you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376084/changing-url-in-a-codedui-test?rq=1) you'll find directions on how to get your data from your excel sheet.

Then you could put that data into:

```
BrowserWindow window = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri(urlFromExcel));
```

Comment: i dont have any problems with taking data from excel. i guess i wrote this more complicated than it is. forget excelsheets :)
 i need to change the url value in my coded ui test.

Comment: OK, so you only need the second part telling you where to put the data? The code I included will launch a new browser with any url you give it, from excel, etc. Is that what you needed? If you have a browser object in your UIMap you can still use the example in the link to set map the newly launched browser to the mapped control for testing.

Comment: i couldnt find the browser object, this.UIMAP... after this i cant find the browser parameter...

Comment: I'm going to guess it's name is something like UIBlankPageWindowsInteWindow and it should be of type BrowserWindow or it'll be public UIBlankPageWindowsInteWindow UIBlankPageWindowsInteWindow